# Does transaction.atomic cover the called function too?

Tags: python, django

I'm working with **Django / Celery** and I would like to know if `transaction.atomic` on my create function cover also the called function (`createUserTenant`) too

this is an example (as you can see i'm calling `createUserTenant` which contains some queries) :

```
@transaction.atomic
    def create(self, request):
        formSerializer = CustomUserSerializer(data = request.data)
        if formSerializer.is_valid():
            NewUserRecord = formSerializer.save()

            if createUserTenant.delay(NewUserRecord.id, connection.schema_name):
                return Response(TeamSerializer(Team.objects.all(), many=True).data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return  Response(formSerializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As you can see I have some transactions here

```
@shared_task
def createUserTenant(userid, current_schema):
    state = True
    try:
        with schema_context(current_schema):
            addUserInTeam = Team.objects.create(user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=userid))

        with schema_context('public'):
            userInQuestion = CustomUser.objects.get(id=userid)
            # create your first real tenant
            tenant = Client(
                schema_name=str(userInQuestion.username),
                name=userInQuestion.first_name + '_' + userInQuestion.last_name,
                paid_until='2014-12-05',
                on_trial=True)
            tenant.save() 
            # migrate_schemas automatically called, your tenant is ready to be used!
            # Add one or more domains for the tenant
            domain = Domain()
            domain.domain =  str(userInQuestion.username) + settings.BASE_URL # tx.domain.com
            domain.tenant = tenant
            domain.is_primary = False
            domain.save()
    except:
        state = False
    
    return state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the decorator only wraps the function `create` in a transaction block and transactions can also be nested. A transaction block does not automatically wraps the parent block in a transaction. You need to create a transaction in your task to ensure that the code outside the `create` is being run in a transaction.

Here are more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly

One way to do it:

```
from django.db import transaction
@shared_task
def createUserTenant(userid, current_schema):
    with transaction.atomic():
       # your code
       # ....
```